# How to show line numbers in Vim every N lines?

Tags: vim

I found a NeoVim plugin that does this: https://github.com/IMOKURI/line-number-interval.nvim

But is there a way to show line numbers every N lines in Vim? I would like to try out line numbers every 5 lines, to clear some clutter from the margin.

Comment: AFAIK this is impossible.

Comment: @romainl thanks, I was afraid that would be the case.